# Как удалить окончательно все объекты с FlowPane?

Tags: javafx

Есть FlowPane. Допустим:

```
@FXML
private FlowPane FlowPane;
```

В неё были добавлены объекты типа ImageView(с картинками). 
Хочу удалить все эти объекты с FlowPane. Пытаюсь:

```
FlowPane.getChildren().removeAll();
```

Или же

```
FlowPane.getChildren().clear();
```

С первым вообще нечего не происходит. С вторым лучше. Объекты пропадают, но стоит мне добавить какой-то новый объект на `FlowPane`, так все удалённые снова появляются. Метод `clear();` делает их как бы невидимыми до следующего обновления `FlowPane`. Так собственно как это сделать? Может надо после удаления что-то типо `update();` или `reload();` ?

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

private static ArrayList<Item> ItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
@FXML
private ScrollPane myScrollPane;
@FXML
private ImageView TestImageView;

private static class Item {

    public String ItemsName;
    public String ItemsImage;
    public int ItemsId;
    public int ItemsPrice;

    public String getItemsName() {
        return ItemsName;
    }

    public String getItemsImage() {
        return ItemsImage;
    }

    public int getItemsId() {
        return ItemsId;
    }

    public int getItemsPrice() {
        return ItemsPrice;
    }



}

@FXML
private FlowPane FlowPane;
@FXML
private Button testbutton;

private File file;
private int events;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    FlowPane.setMaxWidth(500);
    FlowPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    FlowPane.setVgap(10);
    FlowPane.setHgap(5);
}

@FXML
private void clicktestbutton(ActionEvent event) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException {

    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader reader;

    reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PriceCalculationForMinecraft\\src\\me\\pricecalculationforminecraft\\items\\Basic_items.xml"));
    events = reader.getEventType();

    while (true) {

        switch (events) {
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                switch (reader.getLocalName()) {
                    case "Item":
                        Item _item = new Item();
                        _item.ItemsName = reader.getAttributeValue(0);
                        _item.ItemsImage = reader.getAttributeValue(1);
                        _item.ItemsId = Integer.parseInt(reader.getAttributeValue(2));
                        _item.ItemsPrice = Integer.parseInt(reader.getAttributeValue(3));
                        ItemsList.add(_item);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        if (!reader.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }

        events = reader.next();
    }

    for (Item _item : ItemsList) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(_item.getItemsImage())));

        image.setId(Integer.toString(_item.getItemsId()));
        image.setFitHeight(40);
        image.setFitWidth(40);
        FlowPane.getChildren().add(image);
        //FlowPane.

        image.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(getIdImage(image));
            } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

        System.out.printf("%s | %s | %s | %s\n", _item.getItemsName(), _item.getItemsImage(), _item.getItemsId(), _item.getItemsPrice());
    }
}

private String getIdImage(ImageView image) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
    TestImageView.setImage(image.getImage());
   //System.out.println(image.getImage().getClass().getField("ItemsPrice"));
    //FlowPane.getChildren().removeAll(image);
    FlowPane.getChildren().clear();
    return image.getId();
}
```

}

Вот видео с ошибкой, что бы понятнее было.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMZznzLnpI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: `removeAll()` и не должен был сработать, т.к. по сигнатуре в него нужно передать массив удаляемого. С `clear()` проблему воспроизвести не смог - всё чётко отработало. Может проблема не с удалением, а с добавлением нового? ( нужно больше кода )

Comment: Добавил код класса в первый пост.

Comment: Вот видео с ошибкой, что бы понятнее было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и предполагалось косяк в добавлении: вы из `FlowPane` все вычистили, но заполняете его из оригинального `ItemsList`, содержащего старые данные.

Вариант решения:

```
FlowPane.getChildren().clear();
ItemsList.clear();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает.